# I can't get values from custom components in Laravel filament

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm trying to create a custom component for my Laravel filament project. Inside my ProductResource, I generate components code inside the foreach loop.

```
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {

        foreach ($filters as $filter) {
            $filterInputs[] = new ProductFilter('filter'.$filter->id, $filter_values[$filter->id] ?? null);
        }

        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\Group::make()
                    ->schema([
                        Forms\Components\Section::make('Product Information')
                        ])
                    ->columnSpan(['lg' => 2]),
                Forms\Components\Group::make()
                    ->schema([
                            
                            Forms\Components\Section::make('Filters')
                            ->schema(array_merge([
                                View::make('custom.alert')
                            ], $filterInputs)),
                        ])
                    ->columnSpan(['lg' => 1]),

            ])->columns(3);
    }
```

My ProductFilter component

```
class ProductFilter extends Component
{
    protected $defaultValue;
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name, $defaultValue = null)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->defaultValue = $defaultValue;
    }

    public function setUp() : void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        if ($this->getState() === null) {
            $this->state($this->defaultValue);
        }
    }

    public function render(): View
    {
        return view('custom.product-filter', [
            'id' => $this->getId(),
            'name' => $this->name, 
            'model' => $this->getModel(),
            'defaultValue' => $this->defaultValue,
        ]);
    }

}
```

And it generates input correctly. It has a name, default value, etc. As an example:

```
<input type="text" id="" name="filter2" value="22" wire:model="filter2">
```

But the problem is, when I post product update form, I can't get filter2 value.

On EditProduct.php, I have save function to customize updating process.

```
public function save(bool $shouldRedirect = true): void
    {
        dd($this->data);
    }
```

$this->data is not containing filter input values.

I tried to generate input by component and field. Also I tried without creating any component, just basic TextInput like;

```
foreach ($filters as $filter) {
            $filterInputs[] = Forms\Components\TextInput::make('filter'.$filter->id)
            ->numeric()
            ->label($filter->title)
            ->default($filter->value);
        }
```

In this scenario, my text inputs did not have the default data I specified.